# Can anyone tell if this component is a solenoid?

Tags: components, solenoid

I need a solenoid for a project, so I took apart an old VCR from Goodwill. I was thinking that the ejector for a VCR tape would controlled by a push solenoid mechanism.

This is a picture of the part I removed including the part number printed on it:

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/67hjs8dbb/image.jpg]

I have tried to find the part number online to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like a dc motor to me

Comment: Any guesses on input voltage?

Comment: http://www.avelmak.sk/show_image.php?article=21333&type=1&name= use Internet it's Motor LOAD B02900

Comment: could be anything but start with 6V

Comment: Only 1/4 of the picture contains anything relevant, and then it has this horrible orange cast.  Really!?

Comment: It has a arrow indicating direction of rotation! Its a motor for crying loud!

Answer (score 3):

That part is not a solenoid. It is a dc brushed motor.

I think so because VCRs typically do not use a solenoid - they use cheap DC motors. You can see an output gear attached on the shaft, furthermore I think the arrow indicates correct direction of rotation. This motor probably was responsible for driving a mechanical mechanism that ejected/pulled in a tape.

Solenoids typically have a spring on the shaft to return to neutral position.

An easy way to test this is attach a 9V battery to it and watch it spin. Voltage of motor is probably up to 12V.

Comment: Thank you! Motor started spinning, an now it won't work anymore...I have it 5v and 9v, why would that happen?

Comment: @Kevin - It likely has failed because the application of 9V to the motor was too much for it to handle. Tiny little motors like these may very well operate normally with voltage lower than 9V. Application of 9V may have burned the brushes inside or blown an inline over current fuse built in series with the wiring inside the motor.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find what's this part is to refer it's service manual.
However service manuals are copyrighted and not freely available for the 
user for the product. They were given to the authorized service centers of
a particular product.

The driver circuit and more info about the motor could be found on the 
service manual.

On Schematic or manual, you would find this part number on their appendix.
on a circuit board you could find some coordinate for a specific part such
as B5 , A4  IC141[K13,schematic 13].

If you have access to the VCR schematic [most probably on the internet], then
you could find out how to drive it.

Comment: Thank you all very much! I didn't think I would blow it with 5/9volts, look like I might've bought a $6 VCR for nothin!